# No autocomplete in android studio with xml possible

Tags: android, xml, autocomplete, android-studio, code-inspection

suddenly my xml injection stopped working on attributes and I do not know how to fix it

[image]

if I press STRG+SPACE, it says "no suggestions".

The namespace seems to be valid, because injection works on adding shapes etc

[image]

Comment: There are many bugs in android studio eclipse it still the best IDE. :)

Comment: I have both IDE´s and for myself android studio is the better choice, even if there are still many bugs